# Table HTML layout

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to setup tables so the result outcomes like this:

[image]

Code:

```
<table width="60%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" id="theBoxer">
<tr style="background: #686868 ;">
<td align="center" valign="top" width="240" height="25" style="border:1px #FFF solid;">About me</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top" width="250" height="112" style="">
Points:<br>
Lalala: <br>
Lalala: <br>
</td>
<td align="left" valign="top" width="250" height="112" style="">
Lalala: <br>
Lalala:
</tr>
</table>
```

Can't get it to work like how I wanted.
The problem I get with my code is that "About me" only covers for the first cell and not the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `colspan="2"` in the `<td>` of the first row so that it spans two columns.

[Semantically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML), you would like to use `<th>` (table heading) instead of `<td>` as well.

**See also:**

- [HTML table tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/tables.php)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<table width="60%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" id="theBoxer">
    <tr style="background: #686868 ;">
        <td align="center" valign="top" colspan="2" width="240" height="25" style="border:1px #FFF solid;" >
            About me
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" width="250" height="112" style="">
        Points:<br>
            Lalala: <br>
            Lalala: <br>
        </td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" width="250" height="112" style="">
            Lalala: <br>
            Lalala:
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note the `colspan` attribute on the first `<td>` tag - this will ensure that it spans the width of two columns.

Additionally, you might also like to expand your `table` to contain the `thead` and `tbody` elements, providing separation between the different sections of content:

```
<table width="60%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" id="theBoxer">
    <thead>
        <tr style="background: #686868 ;">
            <th align="center" valign="top" colspan="2" width="240" height="25" style="border:1px #FFF solid;" >
                About me
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top" width="250" height="112" style="">
                Points:<br>
                Lalala: <br>
                Lalala: <br>
            </td>
            <td align="left" valign="top" width="250" height="112" style="">
                Lalala: <br>
                Lalala:
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```